# Consuming a RESTful Web Service with AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, json, rest, glassfish

I got a problem consuming a web service with  Angular from a client.

I have created a **person.java** class:

```
public class person {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public person(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The Rest service has the following function:

**serviceTest.java**

```
@Path("/service")
public class serviceTest{
    @GET
    @Path("/findall")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Person> findAll(){
        List <Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(new Person("1", "Jason");
        result.add(new Person("2", "Kimberly");
        return result;
        }
    }
```

When I called the `findAll()` function, it returns the following JSON object:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Jason"    
    },

    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Kimberly"  
    }
]
```

Now, in the client I have the **index.jsp** where I call the service with **angular.js** in which I want to show the values in a table:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/javaScript/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="personController">

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="pr in listPerson">
        <td>{{pr.id}}</td>
        <td>{{pr.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    myapp.controller('personController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/wsService/api/service/findall').success(function(data) {
            $scope.listPerson = data;
        });
    });

</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

When I execute java client and the index is loaded, nothing is show in the table:

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Add ng-app="myapp" in your body tag

Comment: he/she  has <html ng-app="myapp">

Comment: Your code is right may be your angular.min.js file is not supporting. What error you r getting ? if possible then share it

Comment: I'm using the AngularJS v1.4.9 and thats the weird part...I'm not gettingt any kind of error...

Comment: try to add your <script> tag in <head>. and I think you haave one extra tag `</form>`

Comment: Could you try $scope.listPerson = data.data; aswell?

Comment: Adding the script in the head doesn't work...@ojus kulkarni thanks for the extra tag, but that did not solve the problem...

Comment: @Orcun Yucel thanks, but this did not work...

Comment: is your ws working fine? check in browser.. you getting proper json?i can see few syntax errors.. but those maybe typo?

Comment: also what is your angular version?

Comment: The web serivice is working fine, my angular version is AngularJS v1.4.9

Comment: try $http.jsonp [...] instead of $http.get

Comment: @AlexArvanitidis thank you, but still not working...there is something i'm missing here...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all, I already did it...

I added a **CORSFilter** class to the web service:

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

public CORSFilter() {
}

public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
}

public void destroy() {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE");
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}

And in the **web.xml**:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.then` instead of `.success` in controller function:

```
myapp.controller('personController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/wsService/api/service/findall').then(function(data) {
            $scope.listPerson = data;
        });
    });
```

Comment: It does not work either. I also test the **angular.js** with other examples and it's working fine...